# Buscar archivo que en su nombre contenga un string determindo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una carpeta con 3 archivos en `F://deportes`

```
tenis_2020.mp4
final_champions_19.mp4
champions_resultados.txt
```

Quiero realizar una búsqueda indicando solo una string, y que encuentre el `*mp4` que contenga dicha string.

Por ejemplo con el string `"champions"` el resultado seria `final_champions_19.mp4`
y ahora pasamos el archivo a la ruta `F://futbol`

Normalmente pongo código bastante cercano al resultado pero solo logre buscar archivos por extensión mp4

```
carpeta = ('F:\deportes')

contenido = os.listdir(carpeta)

   if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(carpeta, fichero)) and fichero.endswith('.mp4'):
       videos.append(fichero)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digamos que ya tienes resuelto el problema de obtener la lista de archivos desde el directorio. No es necesario que la tengas filtrada por extensión.

Entonces, partiendo de que formaste la lista:

```
listado = [
    "/videos/tenis_2020.mp4",
    "/videos/final_champions_19.mp4",
    "/videos/champions_resultados.txt"
    "/videos/champions_resultados.mp4.part"
]
```

puedo usar expresiones regulares para examinar cada archivo y seleccionar los mp4 apropiados al nombre.

La expresión regular, es:

```
f"{nombre}.*\.mp4$"
```

siendo `nombre` una variable que contiene el texto que buscamos. Entonces, si `nombre = "champions"`, la expresión resultante será:

```
"champions.*\.mp4$"
```

que se lee así:

- Tiene "champions" en alguna parte.
- Luego vienen cero o más caracteres cualquiera (`.*`).
- Terminando con ".mp4". La parte `\.` calza con un punto, y el `$` calza con el fin de línea.

Por eficiencia, compilamos esta expresión en un patrón para aplicarlo después:

```
patron = re.compile(f"{nombre}.*\.mp4$")
```

Para saber si un nombre cumple, aplicamos

```
patron.search(archivo)
```

El método `search` examina todo el texto en busca de un lugar donde calce la expresión regular. Si lo encuentra, retorna un `match object`, el que me dice donde y cual cosa se encontró, y `None` en caso contrario.

No estoy interesado en esa información, me basta con chequear que el resultado sea distinto de `None`.

#### Demo

Poniendo todo junto

```
import re

listado = [
    "/videos/tenis_2020.mp4",
    "/videos/final_champions_19.mp4",
    "/videos/champions_resultados.txt"
    "/videos/champions_resultados.mp4.part"
]

while True:
    nombre = input("Nombre a buscar: ")
    patron = re.compile(f"{nombre}.*\.mp4$")
    for archivo in listado:
        if patron.search(archivo):
            print(archivo)
```

produce:

```
Nombre a buscar: champions
/videos/final_champions_19.mp4
Nombre a buscar: resultados
Nombre a buscar: tenis
/videos/tenis_2020.mp4
Nombre a buscar:
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto! muchas gracias